# How to calculate word and sentence embedding using Roberta?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I'm trying to calculate word and sentence embeddings using Roberta, for word embeddings, I extract the last hidden state `outputs[0]` from the `RobertaModel` class, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to calculate.

As for sentence embeddings, I don't know how to calculate them, this is the code I have tried:

```
from transformers import RobertaModel, RobertaTokenizer
import torch

model = RobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
captions = ["example caption", "lorem ipsum", "this bird is yellow has red wings", "hi", "example"]

encoded_captions = [tokenizer.encode(caption) for caption in captions]

# Pad sequences to the same length with 0s
max_len = max(len(seq) for seq in encoded_captions)
padded_captions = [seq + [0] * (max_len - len(seq)) for seq in encoded_captions]

# Convert to a PyTorch tensor with batch size 5
input_ids = torch.tensor(padded_captions)

outputs = model(input_ids)
word_embedding = outputs[0].contiguous()
sentence_embedding = ?????
```

How to calculate word and sentence embeddings using Roberta?

Comment: Does this answer your question (applies to `roberta-base` as well)? [BERT sentence embeddings from transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63461262/bert-sentence-embeddings-from-transformers)

Comment: The answer you linked related to cosine-similarity whereas I just want to calculate sentence embedding and I'm also not sure about the calculate of word embedding is correct ? And also I want to use Roberta only, not other libraries

Comment: Please read more carefully. The answer states that the sentence embeddings you get from `roberta-base` are not meaningful. That means similar captions will be close or far away from each other because the training objective doesn't force meaningful representations.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am currently experimenting only with Roberta, so is not a problem if the sentence embeddings are not meaningful

Comment: @cronoik, in the `RobertaModel` class, at [this line](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/4fb3d3a0f6f0da95548a5e6bd02850d468c85e32/src/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py#L853), do you think I could use the `last_hidden_state` as the word embedding, and `pooler_output` as sentence embedding ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning:** This answer only shows ways to retrieve word and sentence embeddings from a technical perspective as requested by OP In the comments. The respective embeddings will not be useful from a performance perspective to for example calculate the similarity between two sentences or words. Compare this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63461262/bert-sentence-embeddings-from-transformers) for further information.

**Word embeddings**

It is important to note, that RoBERTa was trained with a byte-level BPE tokenizer. This is a so-called subword tokenizer which means that one word of your input string can be split into several tokens. For example your second caption `lorem ipsum`:

```py
from transformers import RobertaModel, RobertaTokenizerFast
import torch

m = RobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
t = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
captions = ["example caption", "lorem ipsum", "this bird is yellow has red wings", "hi", "example"]

print(t(captions[1]).input_ids)
```

Output:

```
[0, 462, 43375, 1437, 7418, 783, 2]
```

As you can see the two words were mapped to 5 tokens (`0` and `2` are special tokens). That means to retrieve the actual word embeddings and not the token embeddings, you need to apply some kind of aggregation. A common approach is applying mean pooling (compare this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65699881/6664872)). Using the respective fast tokenizer of the model helps you here because it returns a BatchEncoding object that can be used to map the tokens back to the respective words:

```py
# no need to pad manually, the tokenizer can do that for you
tokenized_captions = t(captions, return_tensors='pt', padding='longest')

with torch.inference_mode():
  model_inference_output = m(**tokenized_captions)
  contextualized_token_embeddings = model_inference_output.last_hidden_state

#properly padded
print(contextualized_token_embeddings.shape)

def fetch_word_embeddings(idx, sentence, tokenized_captions, contextualized_token_embeddings):
  word_embeddings = {}
  # fetching word_ids, each id is a word in the original sentence
  word_ids = {i for i in tokenized_captions[idx].word_ids if i is not None}

  for word_id in word_ids:
    token_start, token_end = tokenized_captions[idx].word_to_tokens(word_id)
    word_start, word_end =  tokenized_captions[idx].word_to_chars(word_id)

    word=sentence[word_start:word_end]
    word_embeddings[word] = contextualized_token_embeddings[idx][token_start:token_end].mean(dim=0)
  
  return word_embeddings

result = []
for idx, sentence in enumerate(captions):
  word_embeddings = fetch_word_embeddings(idx, sentence, tokenized_captions, contextualized_token_embeddings)
  result.append({"sentence": sentence, "word_embeddings":word_embeddings})

# contextualized word embedding of the word `ipsum` of the second caption   
print(result[1]['word_embeddings']['ipsum'].shape)
```

Output:

```
torch.Size([5, 9, 768])
torch.Size([768])
```

**Sentence embeddings**

Sentence embeddings represent the whole sentence in a vector. There are different strategies to retrieve them. Commonly used are `mean` or `cls`-pooling, with `mean-pooling` delivering better results as shown in this [paper section 6](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.10084). The "only" challenge from a technical perspective (compare warning preamble) is, that you want to exclude the padding tokens:

```py
# has 1 for none-padding-tokens and 0 for padding-tokens
attention_mask = tokenized_captions.attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1)

# mutiply the contextualized embeddings with the attention mask to 
# set the padding token weights to zero  
sum_embeddings = torch.sum(contextualized_token_embeddings * attention_mask,1)
print(sum_embeddings.shape)
num_none_padding_tokens = attention_mask.sum(1)
print(num_none_padding_tokens)
sentence_embeddings = sum_embeddings / num_none_padding_tokens
print(sentence_embeddings.shape)
```

Output:

```
torch.Size([5, 768])
tensor([[4],
        [7],
        [9],
        [3],
        [3]])
torch.Size([5, 768])
```

You also wanted to know in the comments if you could use the `pooler_output` of `roberta-base` directly to retrieve the sentence embeddings. Yes, you can do that. The `pooler_output` is retrieved via a form of `cls-pooling` ([code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/4fb3d3a0f6f0da95548a5e6bd02850d468c85e32/src/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py#L573)).

Please note in addition to the warning preamble that the layers used for to generate the `pooler_output` are randomly initialized (i.e. untrained) for the `roberta-base` weights you load. That means they are even less meaningful!

```
Some weights of RobertaModel were not initialized from the model checkpoint at roberta-base and are newly initialized: ['roberta.pooler.dense.weight', 'roberta.pooler.dense.bias']
```

Comment: I read some code that used `NLTK tokenizer` instead of `Roberta tokenizer` to handle words that might be split into sub-tokens, like the caption "lorem ipsum". So, NLTK breaks the caption into "lorem" and "ipsum", then build a dictionary for all captions with increasing indices, something like `{"example": 1, "lorem": 2, "ipsum": 3, etc.}`. The input ids for "lorem ipsum" are `[2, 3, 0, 0, 0]`, then forward these ids to the `RobertaModel` to get word embedding. Do you think this approach would be effective ?

Comment: @David: That will only work when you train your own transformer. The `roberta-base` model you are using maps the ids it gets from the tokenizer to trained vectors. You can't just redefine the words/tokens the ids represent without changing the model. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77605657/how-to-understand-contextualized-embeddings-in-transformer/77611233#77611233) for more details.

Comment: My answer already covers this point and shows the code to exclude them. You want to exclude them because otherwise the vector representing a string changes based on the number of padding tokens. That doesn't make any sense. @David

Comment: Thank you, I tried to apply your word embedding method, but my program only accepts word embeddings of the shape `torch.Size([5, 9, 768])` instead of `torch.Size([768])`. Are there any solutions or workarounds to use your method while keeping the `torch.Size([5, 9, 768])` output shape ? Thanks.

Comment: In the example above `5, 9, 768` are the word_embeddings (plural!) of all 5 captions. The single `768` tensor represents the word `ipsum`. Maybe open a separate question in case you are struggling.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking the mean of the word embeddings from the last hidden layer can give you the sentence embedding for that sentence.
If you dont want to do that and want something automatic then you check out sentence transformers like [S-BERT](https://www.sbert.net) and many more

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the average of the last hidden states, here is an updated code ([source](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/27600)):

```
from transformers import RobertaModel, RobertaTokenizer
import torch

model = RobertaModel.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained('roberta-base')
captions = ["example caption", "lorem ipsum", "this bird is yellow has red wings", "hi", "example"]

encoded_captions = [tokenizer.encode(caption) for caption in captions]

# Pad sequences to the same length with 0s
max_len = max(len(seq) for seq in encoded_captions)
padded_captions = [seq + [0] * (max_len - len(seq)) for seq in encoded_captions]

# Convert to a PyTorch tensor with batch size 5
input_ids = torch.tensor(padded_captions)
outputs = model(input_ids, output_hidden_states=True)
# average of the last 
word_embedding = outputs.hidden_states[-1].mean(dim=1)
```

However to get the best embeddings, you should use models trained for sentence embedding see [SentenceTransformers Documentation](https://www.sbert.net/).

You can choose model from the [Pretrained Models](https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html) or from [huggingface](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers?search_models=Roberta-base)

Another option, is to fine-tune your own sentence embeddings model see [Training Overview](https://www.sbert.net/docs/training/overview.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I want to ask why are they also calculate embedding for padding tokens, they should be 0, can you explain ?

Comment: @David I m not sure , see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55739446/18963373